# Find overlapping or conflicting time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

Hello I have question to the mysql query (DQL)

Table:

```
id| start | end   | day
-------------------------------
1 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 03-05-2013
2 | 11:00 | 12:00 | 03-05-2013
3 | 10:30 | 12:00 | 03-05-2013
4 | 13:00 | 14:00 | 03-05-2013
5 | 14:00 | 15:00 | 03-05-2013
```

And as a result i want to get (columns: id, start, end) only rows which have the same part between start and end. So as a result i would like to get:

```
id| start | end   
------------------
1 | 10:00 | 11:00 
2 | 11:00 | 12:00 
3 | 10:30 | 12:00
```

Because rows 1 and 3 have same time between: 10:30 and 11 and rows 2,3 have the same time between 11:00 to 12:00

I Hope it's clear what i want to get as an output.
Would be, great to get answer in DQL syntax for doctrine.

Comment: . . And why wouldn't you get rows 4 and 5?  These seem to meet the same conditions as 1 and 2.

Comment: Because rows 4 and 5 are independent in time, there are no other rows which are between start and end of those rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to self-join the table and look for conflicts between pairs

```
SELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.start,
  t1.end
FROM table_name t1
JOIN table_name t2
WHERE
  t1.start < t2.end AND
  t2.start < t1.end AND
  t1.id <> t2.id AND
  t1.date = t2.date
```

You can use a SELECT DISTINCT or a GROUP BY to trim the duplicates in the output.